# Sturm-Liouville Eigenvalue Problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I would like some help with the following problem. Thanks for any help in advance.

Consider the eigenvalue problem $Lu≡−((e^x)u′)′ =λu \space 0 < x < l$, and

$u(0)=u(l)=0$

Is $λ = 0$ an eigenvalue of $L$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$e^xu'+e^xu''= -\lambda u$.

**Case :** $\lambda=0$

So $u''+u'=0 \quad( e^x\ne 0)$

Auxiliary equation :
$m^2+m=0, \quad then$ $\quad m=0,-1$

$\therefore u(x)=c_1+c_2e^{-x}$
$u(0)=0 \implies c_1+c_2=0$
$u(l)=0 \implies c_1+\dfrac{c_2}{e^l}=0$
This is possible iff $c_1=c_2=0$.

Hence $\lambda=0$ is not an eigen value.

Comment: Your solution is correct, but it is not the number 1, it is $l$

Comment: See now, I have edited it.

Comment: I see what you did.